# How to disable a form when a popup-ish form is being shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, focus

I have a "main" form (`form1`).
Within that form I successfully open another form (`form2`) - but - when that form is open, you can still control the underlying form (`form1`).

I don't want the user to be able to do so, and whenever he tries to click on it or something, the popped-up form (`form2`) should gain focus/flash a bit, with some default Windows sound.
I've just described how it acts if the popup window is a FileSave/OpenDialog. Those dialogs work exactly as I want them to work.

I've tried setting `form2.Owner = form1;` but that did not result in the desired effect.

So my question basically is: how can I get the same effect of focus/etc. on a form - just how it is on a Save/OpenDialog?

Thanks,

~ Tgys

Comment: Do you know about usercontrols? They inhert from the Form class and you can just place them temporarily over your main Form so you don't need loads of different Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open the `form2` use [`form2.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

In `form1` class

```
form2 form2Object = new form2();
form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

This way form1 will remain in the background and un-clickable until form2 is shown. You can also return the dialog result from form2 if you want. Code from MSDN.

```
  Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

   // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
   if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
      this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;
   }
   else
   {
      this.txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
   }
```